# C# SerialDevice no port information (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I have two USB receivers for bar-code scanners connected to a raspberry pi3 (Windows IOT Core).

I can connect to them and list the USB Virtual COM devices and connect to them and receive data. But I can't differentiate between the two, the IDs are identical and the system is not providing Port numbers.

When I call Current.portnumber.ToString()  the string is empty.

I am hoping to assign each device to a person and have them scan a bar-code for their username and would like to display which scanner is associated with which person  (Such as Com5 = Bill Com6 = Dave) but just can't find a unique identifier for each virtual com

```
private async void ListAvailablePorts()
        {
            try
            {
                string aqs = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
                var infos = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);

                foreach (var info in infos)
                {
                    var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(info.Id);
                    DeviceInformation Current = info as DeviceInformation;
                    if (serialDevice != null && Current.Name == "USB Virtual COM")
                    {
                        listOfDevices.Add(Current);
                        ComList.Items.Add(Current.Name.ToString());
                    }
                }

                DeviceList.ItemsSource = listOfDevices;

                ComList.SelectedIndex = -1;
                DeviceList.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtUser.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

After additional scrutiny I found that the ID fields are different on a single digit within an 86 character string.

\\?\USB#VID_0416&PID_5011#5&3753427a&0&**5**#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}

VS

\\?\USB#VID_0416&PID_5011#5&3753427a&0&**2**#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73}

Thanks

Comment: Can you plug these into a desktop computer and look at the USB descriptors with "USB View"?  One of the parts that's common between the two strings you show, I believe is supposed to be the unique USB serial number.  But not all manufacturers actually serialize their devices correctly...  If you find that the serial number is the same on both devices, do the rest of the world a favor and report the violation of the USB standard to USB Implementer's Forum.  Serial numbers are optional, but if provided, they're supposed to be unique.